# How to break recieve messages for 20 minutes after recieve for one time?

Tags: javascript, websocket

I have a websocket client that listens for incoming messages.
When a name is received, which is what I'm waiting for, it should be printed immediately in the console. It happens that the same name is sent from the server several times within minutes. At this point I would like to take a break of 20 minutes for this name. but not for other names. I'm very grateful for any help as I'm still learning.

This is a snippet from my client.which also works in my client

```js
socket.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
  event.data.text().then((dat) => {
    if (dat.includes("example")) {
      var A = dat.replace(/.*?({.*}).*/, "$1");
    } else return;

    if (A.match(/exapleMessage/)) {
      var at = JSON.parse(A);
      var AK = at.M[0].M.OID;
    }

    if (AK >= 0) {
      var targetID = at.M[0].M.TID;
      var attacker = at.M[0].M.OID;
      at.O.forEach(player);

      function player(item) {
        var oid = item.OID;

        if (targetID === oid) {
          targetName = item.N;
        }
        if (attacker === oid) {
          allianceName = item.AN;
        }
        if (typeof alliance === "undefined") {
          alliance = "none Alliance";
        }
        if (attacker === oid) {
          attackerName = item.N;
        }
      }

      var typeOfAttack = at.M[0].ATT;
      var targetCastle = at.M[0].M.TA[10];
      var targetX = at.M[0].M.TA[1];
      var targetY = at.M[0].M.TA[2];
      var targetcoordinate = targetX + ":" + targetY;

      if (typeof targetName === "undefined") {
        var target = targetcoordinate;
      } else {
        var target = targetName;
      }

      function secondsToTime(seconds) {
        const arr = new Date(seconds * 1000)
          .toISOString()
          .substr(11, 8)
          .split(":");

        const days = Math.floor(seconds / 86400);
        arr[0] = parseInt(arr[0], 10) + days * 24;
        return arr.join(":");
      }

      var t1 = at.M[0].M.TT - at.M[0].M.PT;

      const allArrs = [
        ...at.M[0].GA.L,
        ...at.M[0].GA.M,
        ...at.M[0].GA.R,
        ...at.M[0].GA.RW,
      ];

      const result = allArrs.reduce((accumulator, currentArray) => {
        accumulator += currentArray[1];
        return accumulator;
      }, 0);

      if (targetName === "John") {
        console.log("NAME: " + targetName);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: What does this do `+Name`? 

Answer (score 0):

It's essentially quite simple. You just need to maintain a list of names that you want to ignore and check that every time you receive a message. If the name is on the list you ignore the message. If the name is not on the list you put it on the list and schedule a task to remove it from the list after a certain amount of time using [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout). Now, to do that efficiently for a large number of different names you should use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) which is efficient for lookups. For relatively small numbers of names a array will be faster.

Here a small example using that approach which uses a button and an input field to allow you to simulate an incoming WebSocket message and logs some explanatory sentences:

```js
const ignoredNames = new Set();
const ignoreForInMillisecons = 2000; // 2 seconds; for 20 minutes use 1000 * 60 * 20;

function onMessageReceived(name, processMessage) {
  console.log(`Received message for name '${name}'`);
  if (ignoredNames.has(name)) {
    console.log(`Ignoring message for name '${name}' since the name is on the ignore list`);
    return; // if we have this name in the ignore list, ignore this message => return
  }
  ignoredNames.add(name); // add name to names to ignore
  console.log(`Added '${name}' to ignore list`);
  setTimeout(() => {
    ignoredNames.delete(name);
    console.log(`At least ${ignoreForInMillisecons}ms have passed. Removed '${name}' from ignore list`);
  }, ignoreForInMillisecons); // schedule a task to remove the name from the the list after a certain amount of time
  processMessage(name); // call the actual callback which processes messages that are not ignored
}

function logName(name) {
  console.log(`Name: ${name}`);
}

const simulateMessageButton = document.getElementById("simulateWebSocketMessageBtn");
const messageInput = document.getElementById("messageInput");
simulateMessageButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  // button was clicked => we simulate that a message has arrived
  // get message content
  const messageContent = messageInput.value;
  onMessageReceived(messageContent, logName); // we provide the message content and a function which should be called to process the messsage
});
```

```html
<label for="messageInput">Name:</label>
<input id="messageInput" />
<button id="simulateWebSocketMessageBtn">Simulate an incoming WebSocket message</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggested solution.
I'll test it tomorrow at the latest. And then I'll let you know

Comment: @Jeffrey any luck so far? :)

Comment: Unfortunately no. Somehow it doesn't work for me.

Now I have another thought.
There are only about 25 names that I keep waiting for.
What would be the best way to count the names?
Example: let i = 0;    if(name === 'john'){ ++i}  if( i<=1 ) { console.log(name) What do you mean ? Is this possible or not so good ?

Comment: Ok, what exactly doesn't work? Do you get any errors?
As for part two of your comment: You can certainly increase a counter in `onMessageReceived()` (counter should be created outside of the function) and then you'd know how many messages/ names you have received. But you wouldn't know which names you have (not) received. Hard to tell what exactly you'd want to do, but sounds definitely different from what you've asked here. Probably best to ask another more specific question on StackOverflow with your code and a specific problem. The comments are not the place for these kind of things.

Comment: @ 
Mushroomator
Now I edit my Question. I hope is better so ?

Comment: @ Mushroomator  Thx for Edit :-)   I'm still learning. Several factors are important to me in the incoming message. Name, time, number of attackers.
If the name and number of attackers is greater than 100, this information will be forwarded to the corresponding player via whats up. The problem is, if there are too many messages in a row in a short time, then you will be banned from whats up. And I have to prevent this. I apologize to you that I couldn't explain my problem properly